# is it possible to create python package like in java?

Tags: java, python, tkinter

I have few confusion which m not able to get clear from any source! Like in java we can create a package and add many class file on it which can be called by another class (basically when one create an application which contain too many windows and functions)

**for example:**
I have created splash_screen.java and main_window.java which can be called and destroyed in index.java

Is there something like that in Python using Tkinter?
If so then how is it possible.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're actually after but packages and UI are not really related. In Java a package is a tool to organize classes and their visibility, i.e. which other classes or packages have access to them. How your UI is organized doesn't have anything to do with that.

Comment: This is what a Python [module](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#modules) does.

Answer (score 0):

Packages are different from GUI. To create a package, make a folder for example - Package1
.Then make an `__init__.py` file. You don't need to write anything in this. It can be empty. You just need to name an empty file as `__init__.py` and then place it in the folder.  `__init__.py` is just used for python to detect that the folder is a package. Then, you can place many more sub-packages or modules in this package.

Refer to this [Python Packages](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_packages.php#:%7E:text=A%20package%20is%20basically%20a,as%20a%20package%20by%20)